# Custom Rest Service in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-services, rest

I'm currently developing a custom wcf rest webservice on sharepoint 2010, but I keep getting the message Endpoint not configured
Im deploying the webservice on a _ISAPI solution folder.
Here's the code.

First, The service markup

```
<%@ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
Service="MS.InformationManagement.Services.VoBoService, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Now, the Service contract:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using MS.InformationManagement.DAL.MobileDTOs;

namespace MS.InformationManagement.Services.WCFServiceContracts
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IVoBoService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json, 
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate= "/FetchVoBos/pi/{pageIndex}/pz/{pageSize}")]
        IEnumerable<VoBoMDTO> FetchVoBos(string pageIndex, string pageSize);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "/Answer/{voboId}/ou/{ouput}/c/{comments}")]
        void Answer(string voboId, string ouput, string comments);

    }
}
```

Now The service class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MS.InformationManagement.Services.WCFServiceContracts;
using MS.InformationManagement.DAL.MobileDTOs;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

namespace MS.InformationManagement.Services
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class VoBoService: IVoBoService
    {
        public IEnumerable<VoBoMDTO> FetchVoBos(string pageIndex, string pageSize)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Answer(string voboId, string ouput, string comments)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally an entry on the Web.config File:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MS.InformationManagement.Services.VoBoService" behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MS.InformationManagement.Services.WCFServiceContracts.IVoBoService" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RestBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you look at this question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45567/wcf-service-endpoint-not-found-but-service-operations-work-ok ? And did you test your service methods directly? Also, you can make services without having to edit web.config

Comment: Yes I did saw the question, and I'm testing the methods using javascript/calling them through the browser's url. I still get the endpoint not found error.

Comment: Have you tried setting up something very simplified, perhaps like this: http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.no/2011/03/sharepoint-2010-create-custom-wcf.html ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok found the issue.
Removed the endopoint from the webconfig file.
So now my system.servicemodel section looks like this

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MS.InformationManagement.Services.VoBoService" behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior"/>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RestBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

Hope this helps if any other has the same issue.
Happy coding

Comment: hello, can you please provide a link to implement this rest service in sharepoint?may be a  step by step guide?